# Password generator shows a sign which doesn't occur in the pool

Tags: c

I have programmed a password generator and it seems to behave awkwardly sometimes. When I start the programm I get sometimes output like this:

> password: pyi>Sx2Z

I actually excluded the "greater than" char. I even printed every available char in the pool and the "greater than" char doesn't occur. I am a bit confused. I appreciate any help or explanation. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STARTNUMBER     '0'
#define ENDNUMBER       '9'
#define STARTUPLETTER   'A'
#define ENDUPLETTER     'z'
#define STARTLOWLETTER  'a'
#define ENDLOWLETTER    'z'
#define SIZE            (2*26+10)
#define DEBUG

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  srand(time(0));
  int defaultLenght = 8;
  if(argc == 2)
  {
    defaultLenght = atoi(argv[1]);
  }
  char pool[SIZE];
  char password[defaultLenght];
  char digitCount = ENDNUMBER - STARTNUMBER + 1;
  for(int c = 0; c < digitCount; c++)
  {
    pool[c] = STARTNUMBER + c;
  }
  char upLetterCount = ENDLOWLETTER - STARTUPLETTER + 1;
  for(int c = 0; c < upLetterCount; c++)
  {
    pool[digitCount + c] = STARTUPLETTER + c;
  }
  char lowLetterCount = ENDLOWLETTER - STARTLOWLETTER + 1;
  for(int c = 0; c < lowLetterCount; c++)
  {
    pool[digitCount + lowLetterCount + c] = STARTLOWLETTER + c;
  }
#ifdef DEBUG
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", pool[i]);;
  }
  printf("\r\n");
#endif
  printf("password: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < defaultLenght; i++)
  {
    int index = rand() % SIZE + 1;
    password[i] = pool[index];
    pool[index] = pool[SIZE -i -1];
    putchar(password[i]);
  }
  printf("\r\n");
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `'z'` is an awfully odd value for `ENDUPLETTER`, not that it matters, as your upper-case range appears to be using `ENDLOWLETTER - STARTUPLETTER + 1` regardless. There are six non-alphanumeric values sandwiched between the upper and lower case ranges in regular ASCII. Your `SIZE` doesn't seem to account for that.

Comment: I hope you do not intent to use this IRL. `rand` is bad. Really, terribly bad.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It's just for practice purposes intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in the random index selection into the pool by using

```
int index = rand() % SIZE + 1;
```

which gixes a number in the range `1..SIZE` but the pool needs an index in the range `0..(SIZE-1)`. This can result in the next character outside the array being chosen. So that line should be

```
int index = rand() % SIZE;
```

But there is another problem with your password selection. You overwrite the chosen character with another from the pool array, presumably to prevent it being selected twice, but you don't reduce the size of the pool. I suggest this:

```
int poolsize = SIZE;
for(int i = 0; i < defaultLenght; i++)
{
    int index = rand() % poolsize;
    password[i] = pool[index];
    pool[index] = pool[--poolsize];
    putchar(password[i]);
}
```